# Obtaining data from RTK query endpoint

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have got the correct response from the api call done by RTK query, the trouble is accessing that data. I have followed the guide here https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/usage-without-react-hooks on how to interact with RTK Query when used without React Hooks. These are my relevant files:

**actor-slice-api.js**

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

// Define a service using a base URL and expected endpoints
export const actorApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'actorApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_MOVIE_DB_BASE_URL }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getActorByName: builder.query({
      query: (name) => `search/person?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&query=${name}`,
    }),
  }),
})

// Export hooks for usage in functional components, which are
// auto-generated based on the defined endpoints
export const { useGetActorByNameQuery } = actorApi
```

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
// Or from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import { setupListeners } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'
import { actorApi } from '../features/actor/actor-slice-api'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    // Add the generated reducer as a specific top-level slice
    [actorApi.reducerPath]: actorApi.reducer,
  },
  // Adding the api middleware enables caching, invalidation, polling,
  // and other useful features of `rtk-query`.
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(actorApi.middleware),
})

// optional, but required for refetchOnFocus/refetchOnReconnect behaviors
// see `setupListeners` docs - takes an optional callback as the 2nd arg for customization
setupListeners(store.dispatch)
```

**actorSearchContainer.js**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import ActorSearch from './ActorSearch'

import { actorApi } from '../../features/actor/actor-slice-api'

const mapState = (state) => ({
  actors: actorApi.endpoints.getActorByName.select()(state)
});
const mapDispatch = {
  getActors: actorApi.endpoints.getActorByName.initiate,
};
const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch);

export default connector(ActorSearch)
```

**actorSearch.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ActorCard from '../../components/ActorCard'
import SearchBar from '../../components/SearchBar.js'
import Navigation from '../../components/Navigation'
import Styled from 'styled-components'
import SectionTitle from '../../components/SectionTitle'

const SectionContent = Styled.div`
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  padding: 34px 5%;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: white;
`

class ActorSearch extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { actors: [] }
    this.searchChangeHandler = this.searchChangeHandler.bind(this)
  }
  unsubscribe = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    const { getActors } = this.props;
    const { unsubscribe } = getActors("denzel washington");

    // Store the unsubscribe promise for later use
    this.unsubscribe = unsubscribe;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Unsubscribe the component from the cached data when unmounting
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  searchChangeHandler(event) {
    const searchTerm = event.target.value
    this.props.getActors(searchTerm)
  }
  render() {
    const { data = [] } = this.props.actors
    
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation
          bg="dark"
          theme="dark"
          searchBar={
            <SearchBar type="actors" onChange={this.searchChangeHandler} />
          }
        />
        <SectionContent>
          <SectionTitle title="Actor" />
          {data &&
            data.map((profile, i) => {
              return <ActorCard key={i} index={i + 1} profile={profile} />
            })}
        </SectionContent>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ActorSearch
```

In the final file data is always `data = []` instead of the result returned from the api call.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are using legacy class components at this point? Is this a pre-2019 project that cannot be updated to React 16.8?